# Механизм загрузки изображения с Android в БД - api

Tags: java, android, rest

Подскажите, возможно глупый вопрос но все же ответ на него найти я не могу. Мне нужно реализовать загрузку изображений на сервер, api свой на Java, взаимодействие  происходит по rest, можно ли передать файл по json или есть какие-то другие решения для данной проблемы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да можно, можете передать ваш файл как base64 реперезентацию и на самом сервере конвертировать обратно в файл.

**Пример:** (передавай `encoded` значение на сервер)

```
File file = new Files("your_file");
byte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
String encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(data);
```

На серевере который реализует *restApi*:

```
byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(encoded);
Path result = Paths.get("your_file");

if(!Files.exists(result)) {
    result = Files.createFile(result);
}
Files.write(result, bytes);
```

Импорты:
`org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` для **FileUtils**

`import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` дла **DatatypeConverter**